# How to print a specific column with awk on a remote ssh session?

Tags: ssh, awk

When using

```
df -h | grep /dev/root | awk '{print $5}'
```

I get the usage of my SD Card in my Pi: `78%`

But when I use

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/key user@server "df -h | grep /dev/root | awk '{print $5}'"
```

from another computer, I get:

```
/dev/root       7.2G  5.3G  1.6G  78% /
```

Full `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.2G  5.3G  1.6G  78% /
devtmpfs        364M     0  364M   0% /dev
tmpfs           368M   68K  368M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           368M  5.2M  363M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           368M     0  368M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60M   21M   40M  35% /boot
tmpfs            74M  4.0K   74M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Try scaping the `$` with a backslash: `"df -h | grep /dev/root | awk '{print \$5}'"`

Comment: escape the dollar, it's being expanded by the shell before ssh.

Comment: `df /dev/root --output=pcent | tail -1`

Comment: @Costas `df: ‘/dev/root’: No such file or directory`. The Pi handles the storage different than other Linux.

Comment: @Motte001 Show full output `df -h` I'l help to set the right command

Comment: @Costas Already have gotten a solution

Comment: Escape the dollar; it will collapse within a few decades

Comment: @Motte001, `df --output=pcent / | tail -n 1` works regardless of the device name.  It's a shame there's no option in `df` to omit the header line, or to use tabs as field separators.  but, for example, `df --output=target,fstype,pcent  | awk 'NR > 1 && $2 ~/^(ext[2-4]|xfs)$/ {print $1,$3}' OFS='\t'` works well enough.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're hitting a quoting problem; the `$5` is being interpreted at the wrong time.  There are at least two solutions:

1. Put a `\` before the `$`; e.g.

   ```
   /usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/key user@server "df -h | grep /dev/root | awk '{print \$5}'"
   ```
2. Run the `df` remotely but the `grep` and `awk` locally.  e.g.

   ```
   /usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/key user@server df -h | grep /dev/root | awk '{print $5}'
   ```

FWIW, I'd run a version of the second option but merging `grep` and `awk`

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/key user@server df -h | awk '/\/dev\/root/ {print $5}'
```

Comment: +1 for "merging grep & awk" ... if you use awk anyway there's really no need for grep. :)

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/key user@server "df -h | grep /dev/root | awk '{print \$5}'"
```

Notice the `\` included before the `$`. Without this, the local shell will expand the empty variable `$5` and send that to the remote server. Essentially, printing the entire line.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, another way is to use the fact `$n` in `awk` isn't a special case of `$variable` syntax like shell, but instead the `$` operator applied to an integer expression:

```
(ssh key&remote) "df -h | grep /dev/root | awk '{print $ 5}'"
```

or combined as

```
(ssh key&remote) "df -h | awk '/\\/dev\\/root/ {print $ 5}'"
# can use [/] instead of ugly \\/ in gawk, but maybe not others
```

or maybe better as a variable

```
(ssh key&remote) "df -h | awk -vm=/dev/root '$ 0 ~ m {print $ 5}'"
```

But personally I'd go with Stephen Harris' preference to run the `awk` locally.

Comment: Huh, 25 years of using `awk` and I'd not spotted that subtlety!  Nice.