# SSH twice and run command, escaping character?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, top, escape-characters

I'm able to get the desired output by running this command on terminal:

```
top -bn 1 | grep "^ " | awk '{ printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s\n", $1, $2, $9, $10, $6, $11, $12); }' | head -n 6
```

And I'm able to SSH twice and get the hostname by running this on terminal:

```
ssh 192.168.5.209 "ssh 192.168.5.210 exec \"hostname\""
```

The 209 is serving as something like a portal so I can only SSH from 209 to 210. But the problem is how do I replace the "hostname" with the top command that I write above? There are too much special characters.

I am writing a script to execute from PHP btw.

Comment: It may be preferable to install your first snippet as a script in your x.x.x.210 server, and have your ssh commands call for that script directly.

Comment: i mean, my manager need the script on the project root directory

Comment: You only need to run the `top -bn 1` on the target; you can do the filtering and formatting locally, with only normal (local) quoting. And FWIW you don't need grep and head, awk can subsume both of those -- but that wasn't your question. Similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294676/how-to-print-a-specific-column-with-awk-on-a-remote-ssh-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep, awk, and head can be merged and run locally

```
 ssh 192.168.5.209 "ssh 192.168.5.210 top -bn 1 " |
 awk '/^ / { printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s\n", $1, $2, $9, $10, $6, $11, $12); c++ ; if (c==6) exit ;}
```

where

- `/^ /` search for line starting with a space
- `c++ ; if (c==6) exit ;` will exit awk after 6 line printed.

Comment: hmmm... it seems to work. but now i'm getting another error : 'dumb': unknown terminal type. do you by any chance know what it is?

Comment: try TERM=xterm before ssh