# grep with pipe and variables NOT working on remote server through ssh (working locally)

Tags: linux, ssh, grep, pipe, remote

Below grep command is not giving expected result (matching line number) if I run it through ssh from a remote machine (passwordless authentication enabled). Variables have been defined correctly as well.

From Server 1 :

```
ssh user@server2 grep -n -i $J2C_ID1 $CUST_NODE_PATH1/resources.xml | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d ':'
```

above command returns blank output.

From Server 2 (running locally) returns expected output i.e., a line number:

```
grep -n -i $J2C_ID1 $CUST_NODE_PATH1/resources.xml | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d ':' 

474
```

(expected out i.e., a line number of matching string specified in $J2C_ID, on the specified file resources.xml)

I tried modifying the command which is giving me full line as output, though I just need the line number and not the full line:

```
ssh user@server2 grep -n -i "'$J2C_ID1' '$CUST_NODE_PATH1/resources.xml' | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d ':'"

474        <resourceProperties xmiid="J2EEResourceProperty" name="Password" type="java.lang.String" value="null" description="password" required="false" ignore="false" confidential="false" supportsDynamicUpdates="false"/>
```

Need to get rid of redundant text and see just the line number as o/p.

Can you please help fix the command to run successfully and return the line number of matching string IF run as ssh from another server? Quick help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [How to print a specific column with awk on a remote ssh session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294676/how-to-print-a-specific-column-with-awk-on-a-remote-ssh-session)

Comment: It worked after putting a \ before $1 in awk command! Thanks so much @steeldriver , You rock! :)

Comment: @steeldriver - If I am trying to save the o/p into variable , its still showing the full string and not just the line number.  how can i correctly save just the line number output into a variable ?